# Generate google search result for my website like that of flipkart

Tags: search

I have my website which i can search in google and it comes up. But if i see flipkart search result on google, it is structured very well. Is there any module to do that in drupal?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this technique is call Rich Snippets and this might be a cool module for you: https://www.drupal.org/project/schemaorg